# Correct way to read 'echo json_encode( )' from JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo, json

I am using: echo json_encode($Response); to send an Associative array back to JQuery Ajax. Whenever I try to read each ID key value I get an undefined value. Please help me figure out what I am doing so wrong... Thanks in advance

My PHP Code:

```
$Stuff = 'Hello world';

$Success = true;
$Content = $Stuff;

$Response = array('Success' => $Success, 'Content' => $Content);
echo json_encode($Response);
```

#

#

My JS code:

```
var sFirstName     = $('#student_first_name').attr('value');  

$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "../pgs/UpdateEditAStudent.php", 
    data: "FirstName="+ sFirstName ,  

    //The below code will give me: {"Success":true,"Content":"Hello world"}
    success: function(data){$("#Ajax_response").html(data);}

    //The popup window will show me "Undefined"
    //and: {"Success":true,"Content":"Hello world"}
    success: function(data){$("#Ajax_response").html(data); alert(data.Content);}
});
```

Answer (score 10):

You should set the mime type aswell, wich, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) is `application/json`. Then jQuery will understand the answer is a json element. To do it, you'd do the following:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

In your `UpdateEditAStudent.php` before printing anything.

Comment: @Lumbenil. Thank you very much. What is the advantage of your solution compared to defining the correct datatype in $.ajax dataType: "json", as Niklaas suggested?

Comment: Simply correctness of the `UpdateEditAStudent.php`, since now Apache (or whatever the webserver is) is telling to anyone downloading that the given URL is an HTML page (mime type `text/html`) instead of it's true mime type, that is `application/json`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to add a header to the PHP file, just use this [Jquery parseJSON function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

Keep this PHP code as it is:

```
$Stuff = 'Hello world';

$Success = true;
$Content = $Stuff;

$Response = array('Success' => $Success, 'Content' => $Content);
echo json_encode($Response);
```

And for the JS:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "../pgs/UpdateEditAStudent.php",
    data: "FirstName="+ $('#student_first_name').val(),

    success: function(data){
        // Here is the tip
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);

        alert(data.Content);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the correct `dataType` or provide the correct header, as Lumbendil described.

You can manually define the `dataType` to `json`, so your code would look like:

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "GET",  
    url: "../pgs/UpdateEditAStudent.php", 
   data: "FirstName="+ sFirstName ,  
   dataType: "json",
   ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an array. You should probably do alert(data['Content']);.

Comment: Javascript `arrays` with key=>value?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
$Stuff = 'Hello world';

$Success = true;
$Content = $Stuff;

$Response = array('Success' => $Success, 'Content' => $Content);
echo json_encode($Response);
```

Comment: He asked about encode from JQuery. You gave a example of a array from php. He already did it.