# VM5894:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I keep getting an error parsing what seems to be valid JSON.
The parse call is done ina handler to an Ajax call to a php script that is returning:

```
echo json_encode(array("success"=> false, "error_message"=> "error"));
```

The code bit handling the response:

```
function(returnedData){
                console.log(returnedData);
                var response = JSON.parse(returnedData);
```

The console.log call is printing

> {"success":false,"error_message":"error"}

If I take this, put it between quotes and manually call JSON.parse in the console, then it works fine.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your json isn't json. It's html + json, most likely a php warning/error, causing the json to be considered corrupted, Look at the RAW response from the server to see what this html is.

Comment: My guess is that your PHP file is returning HMTL, not your JSON. Check the network tab in your console

Comment: I can't see any way that `console.log(returnedData);` could give output that doesn't include a `<` character when `var response = JSON.parse(returnedData);` throws an error complaining about a `<` character.

Comment: It looks as if the data sent by the server has plain text format. Follow [this procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6599300/1505348) to use JSON format instead. And please reply here if it does work :)

Comment: That was it! Thanks guys!